# How do I implement a mouseover function on mobile devices?

Tags: html

I have created a price list for computers with a list of wares to different prices. But when one puts the mouse over a price, one can see more information about that price, including cost and profit. This works poorly on mobile devices.

How can I get this to work without installing extra modules?

The function i use now is:

```
<div title="Ware: Something&#13;&#13;
  Price: 2499&#13; Kost: 2000.00&#13;Profit: 899">2499</div>
```

Comment: Mobile have no mouse over.... You should open a dialog box with more info or other page.. I think

Comment: As your `div`does not contain any link, you can manage the `ontouch` event with javascript and show an `absolute` positioned `div` next to it, containing the informations you want to provide.

Comment: Vincent, thank you. Do you have a link or a description to how this would work? JavaScript is not my strongest side, more a weak side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out by searching a way to make the function I like:

```
<script>
function functionAlert(msg) {
   var confirmBox = $("#confirm");
   confirmBox.find(".message").html(msg);
   var myYes = confirmBox.find(".yes");
   myYes.on('click', function() {
      confirmBox.hide();
   });
   //myYes.click(myYes);
   confirmBox.show();
}
</script>
<style>
#confirm {
    display: none;
    background-color: #AADDEE;
    color: #000000;
    border: 2px solid #555;
    position: fixed;
    width: 300px;
    height: 350px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 40%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
}
#confirm button {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #77AABB;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: 3px solid #002244;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60px;
    cursor: pointer;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: auto;
    left: auto;
}
#confirm .message {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
</style>

<div id="confirm">
 <div class="message">
 </div>
 <button class="yes">Lukk</button>
 </div>

<div onclick="functionAlert('Ware: Something<br /><br />Price: 2499<br />Kost: 2000<br />Profit: 899')" title="Ware: Something&#13;&#13;Price: 2499&#13;Kost: 2000&#13;Profit: 899">2499</div>
```